# How can I pass the JSX element from child component to the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx

It is okay to pass the JSX element from parent component to child component through the props.

But as I know it is not recommended to use `useState` to store JSX elements, so I can’t simply pass a callback down to the child and then use it to store a JSX component in the parent’s state.

Is there other way to achieve this?

I’m trying to do this in order to pass the button which will mange the state of one sibling from it to another sibling.

Comment: This smells of bad design. You would need to pass it through state if you went this route. Try to find a way that avoids the need of passing components upwards.

Comment: You don't need to pass down a component. Define both child components with the buttons etc you need and then just pass down a _function_ to the component that updates the state and attach it to a button. Or use component composition. Maybe you could add a [mcve] of your components and how they interact to help us.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass JSX elements from parents to children. Go through this link: https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events

Essentially, your parent components should do all the work of handling states.

The only thing your child components (the buttons) need to take in are event handlers which are defined in your parents.

For example:

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setClicked(true);
  }

  return <TestButton onButtonClicked={handleClick}/>;
}

export default function TestButton({onButtonClicked}) {
  return <button onClick={onButtonClick}/>;
}
```

Notice how the test button does nothing but trigger the event handler that was passed to it from the parent. When the event is triggered, the parent does the work of setting the state of "clicked" from false to true.